# PHP CodeIgniter: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

## Everything seems to work just fine but I keep getting the following error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/ordermodel.php

Line Number: 24

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/ordermodel.php

Line Number: 31

================================================================

In the view i just echo $company_name

Controller:

```
            $city = $this->ordermodel->get_city($order_reference);
            $customerCompanyName = $this->ordermodel->get_company_name($order_reference);
            $data['company_name'] = $customerCompanyName;
```

Model:

```
function get_city($ordernumber) {
    $this->db->where('order_number', $ordernumber);
    $city = $this->db->get('order');

    return $city->row()->city;
}

function get_company_name($ordernumber) {
    $this->db->where('order_number', $ordernumber);
    $companyname = $this->db->get('order');

    return $companyname->row()->company_name;
}
```

Comment: Can you add line numbers or highlight the involved line?

Comment: Would be helpful if we could see models/ordermodel.php

Comment: the involved lines are the return lines in the ordermodel.

Answer (score 1):

Use ther`result()` method, it should elimiate all of your errors

`$row = $city->result(); return $row->city;`

Comment: It should be $row = $city->result, judging from your code. Moreover, it cannot throw a fatal error. Can you paste the error here?

Answer (score 0):

Seem that your query has no results, try:

```
function get_company_name($ordernumber) {
    $this->db->where('order_number', $ordernumber);
    $companyname = $this->db->get('order');

    if ($companyname->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $companyname->row()->company_name;
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: It does have results and as i said - everything is working properly. It echoes the correct values but also shows an error.

Comment: object(stdClass)#80 (3) {
  ["order_number"]=>
  string(10) "ABCDE12345"
  ["city"]=>
  string(7) "glasgow"
  ["company_name"]=>
  string(13) "Great Company"
}